# Capybara save_and_open_page doesn't reflect radio buttons tate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I am trying to select the radio button for the freelancer the code is as follows (when we inspect the element on browser)

```
<label for="registration_payer_type_business"><input checked="checked" id="registration_payer_type_business" name="registration[payer_type]" type="radio" value="business">
          Company
          </label>

<label for="registration_payer_type_freelancer"><input id="registration_payer_type_freelancer" name="registration[payer_type]" type="radio" value="freelancer">
          Freelancer
          </label>
```

I have tried

```
page.choose("registration_payer_type_freelancer")
```

This doesn't give any error but when and save and open page in capybara still the radio box is not selected against freelancer. I would appreciate if people can give example using **xpath** and **choose**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The real issue you're most likely having is that `save_and_open_page` saves the HTML with the current attribute values NOT the current property values . This means the fact that you've selected a radio button (which changes the checked property value, not attribute value, won't necessarily be shown).  You're better off using `save_and_open_screenshot` if you want to see the current state of a page.  That being said below is ways you can select radio buttons.

To select a specific radio button with Capybara you can use the id, name, label text, and value too if needed to make unique (with name for instance)

```
choose('registration_payer_type_freelancer') # id
choose('registration[payer_type]', option: 'freelancer') # name and value to make unique
choose('Freelancer') # label text
choose(option: 'freelancer') # just value if the only radio button with that value
```

In all those cases, if the actual radio button input element is non-visible (for styling purposes, etc) on the page and you want to instead click the visible label you can pass `allow_label_click: true`

```
choose('registration_payer_type_freelancer', allow_label_click: true) # find by id and select by clicking the label if input is non-visible
```

Other options you could use is to just find by CSS (the :css argument can be ignored if your default selector type is the default :css)

```
find(:css, '#registration_payer_type_freelancer').click
```

You could also use XPath queries to locate the element, but they're really not necessary 98% of the time (more people correctly understand CSS and with scoping of finders it can generally be used to get any element), and have issues to be aware of - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md#beware-the-xpath--trap

```
find(:xpath, './/input[@value="freelancer"]').click
```